# Return to default color with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a dropdown menu and I'am using `mouseenter()` function. If mouse enters to my selector's area background-color returning to yellow. But ıf I leave from my selector's area I want to set default colour of my selector's area without using `mouseleave()` function.

How can I fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#l_ev_men").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
        $(this).css("color","black");
    });

    $("#l_ev_men").mouseleave(function(){ // ı dont want to use this function
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use mouseleave?

Comment: You can use .hover() instead of mouse enter/leave - http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Why aren’t you using CSS?

Comment: because ı have many selectors which they are different type, some of them ul, some of them li, div etc..

Comment: You could use the CSS class `#l_ev_men:hover`, but browser support varies. What's the reason to use mouseleave?

Comment: You can't.  You are programatically changing the background color, you will need to programatically change it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually better to change the class using [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).  Even better, you can do something this simple without jquery just using the `:hover` CSS psuedo class.

```
.hoverable:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
    color:black;
}
```

then:

```
<li class="hoverable <otherstuff>">...</li>...
```

or

```
<td class="hoverable <otherstuff>">...</td>...
```

Answer (score 5):

I would recomend adding and removing CSS classes.

```css
#l_ev_men:hover, #l_ev_men.hover {
     color: black;
     background-color: yellow;    
}
```

Not all browsers have support for the :hover pseudo-selector, you can use `addClass()` and  `removeClass()` , this will match the `#l_ev_men.hover` selector on the CSS.

```
$("#l_ev_men").hover(
    function in(){ 
         $(this).addClass("hover"); 
    }, 
    function out(){ 
         $(this).removeClass("hover");  
    }
);
```